# "../../src/filesdb.c:683: findnamenode: Assertion `(*pointerp)->name[0] == '/'' failed."

Tags: dpkg

I have been trying to update `Ubuntu 12.04` on the command line by using the two commands

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

which ends with the following error:

```
(Reading database ... 70%dpkg: ../../src/filesdb.c:683: findnamenode: Assertion `(*pointerp)->name[0] == '/'' failed.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg exited unexpectedly
```

How to fix this on the command line?

Comment: This one could be hard to track down. It might be either hardware problems, or a messed-up installation. Please provide complete details in the question of what you did, including commands typed and output.

Answer (score 1):

The solution to this messed up installation is as follows.

1. Remove some installation files

   /var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin  /var/cache/apt/srcpkgcache.bin
2. Run `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` again.
3. Now the output is even more garbled up:

   ```
   Preparing to replace jenkins 1.548 (using .../archives/jenkins_1.549_all.deb) ...
    * Stopping Jenkins Continuous Integration Server    jenkins                                                                [ OK ] 
   Unpacking replacement jenkins ...
   dpkg-deb (subprocess): data: internal gzip read error: '<fd:4>: invalid distance code'
   dpkg-deb: error: subprocess <decompress> returned error exit status 2
   dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/jenkins_1.549_all.deb (--unpack):
    short read on buffer copy for backend dpkg-deb during `./usr/share/jenkins/jenkins.war'
   No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                          * Starting Jenkins     Continuous Integration Server jenkins  [ OK ] 
   Errors were encountered while processing:
    /var/cache/apt/archives/jenkins_1.549_all.deb
   E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
   ```

   but provides a hint of what was incorrectly installed: `jenkins`.
4. Now remove this incomplete installation with `sudo apt-get purge jenkins`.
5. Install it again (if you still need it): `sudo apt-get install jenkins`
6. And finally `sudo apt-get update &&  sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`